# Is the semigroup generated by wellordered positive set wellordered?

Tags: commutative-algebra, order-theory

Let $(A,\leq)$ be a totally ordered abelian group, and $\Gamma\subseteq A$ be a set of nonnegative elements, such that it is wellordered by $\leq$. Is it true then that the semigroup $S$ generated by $\Gamma$ is again wellordered?

Thoughts so far:

- Positivity hypothesis is obviously necessary, because for any negative $a\in A$, we have that $n\cdot a$ is an infinite decreasing sequence.
- I can show that for a wellordered $\Gamma$, it is also true that $\Gamma+\Gamma$ is wellordered, which easily extends to sets $\Gamma_n:=\Gamma+\Gamma+\ldots+\Gamma$ ($\Gamma$ is added $n$ times).
- We assume that $0\in \Gamma$, so that $\Gamma_n\subseteq \Gamma_{n+1}$.
- To show that $S$ is wellordered, we have to show that any $B\subseteq S$ has a smallest element; we can assume without loss of generality that $\Gamma\cap B$ is nonempty (extending $\Gamma$ to some $\Gamma_n$ if necessary).
- With the above assumptions, existence of a minimal element of $B$ is equivalent to the statement that the sequence $b_n:=\min (\Gamma_n\cap B)$ stabilizes.

The motivation of the question is to show that the ring of Hahn series $K((X^A))$ (with $K$ a field) is a field, but even if there's a simpler way to show it, I'm curious about the question on its own.

Thoughts? Hints?

Comment: Do you have an example where this semigroup is not $\omega$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: $\Gamma=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}\subseteq {\bf Z}^2$ with lexicographic ordering? It's still trivial, but...

Comment: Surely you mean the generated subgroup? I don't think this set is closed under addition. Anyway, I was talking about the framework of your assumption, namely the group itself is ordered and the semigroup is all positive elements... (this is why I wrote *this semigroup* and not *a semigroup*)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: well, ${\bf Z}^2$ is ordered and I meant $\Gamma$ as the generating set, as in the question. $\Gamma$ is all positive, as is the semigroup generated by it, ${\bf N}^2\setminus \{0\}$. Which part do you have a problem with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(A,\le)$ be a totally ordered abelian group.

**Lemma.** If $X,Y$ are two wellordered subsets of $A$, then $X+Y$ is wellordered.

*Proof.*
Let $B$ be a nonempty subset of $X+Y$ and assume it has no minimum.
For $b\in B$ let $$x_b=\min\{x\in X\mid \exists y\in Y\colon x+y\in B, x+y<b\}$$
$$y_b=\min\{y\in Y\mid x_b+y\in B\}$$ and $s(b)=x_b+y_b$.
Then $s(b)<b$. This implies $x_{s(b)}\ge x_b$, hence $y_{s(b)}<y_b$

If $b\in B$ is arbitrary, this produces an infinite descending sequence 
$y_b>y_{s(b)}>y_{s(s(b))}>\ldots $
in $Y$, which is impossible. Therefore $B$ must have a minimal element.$_\blacksquare$

**Theorem.** If $\Gamma$ a positive wellordered subset of $A$, then $\langle\Gamma\rangle$ is well-ordered.

As a wellordered set, $\Gamma$ is order-isomorphis to some ordinal $\alpha$.
We proceed by induction on $\alpha$, that is: We may assume that $\langle\Gamma'\rangle$ is wellordered for all $\Gamma'$ of the form $\Gamma'=\{g\in \Gamma\mid g<\gamma\}$ for some $\gamma\in\Gamma$.

Let $B\subset\langle\Gamma\rangle$ be a nonempty set and let $b\in B$ be one of its elements.
If $b=0$, it is clearly minimal in the nonnegative set $\langle \Gamma\rangle$.
If $b\ne 0$, write
$$b=g_1+\cdots +g_n$$
with $n\in \mathbb N$, $g_i\in \Gamma$ and let $\gamma=\max\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$.
Then $b\le n\gamma$.
Consider $b'\in B$ with $b'\le b$ and write 
$$b'=g'_1+\cdots +g'_m$$
with $m\in \mathbb N$, $g'_i\in \Gamma$.
Then at most $n$ of the $g'_i$ are $\ge \gamma$.
All other summands are in  $\Gamma'=\{g\in \Gamma\mid g<\gamma\}$. By induction hypothesis, $\langle\Gamma'\rangle$ is wellordered. By the lemma,
$$T:=\underbrace{(\Gamma\cup\{0\})+\cdots+(\Gamma\cup\{0\})}_n+\langle\Gamma'\rangle$$
is wellordered.
We have just seen that $\{b'\in B\mid b'\le b\}\subseteq B\cap T$, hence
$$\min B =\min(T\cap B).$$
$_\blacksquare$

Comment: Yep, needs rework - I turned some inequalities

Comment: @tomasz: I should have known that showing wellorder would require the full ordinal and transfinite machinery ...

Comment: Well, maybe $<$ should be replaced with $\le$ in the def of $\preceq$. Or $0\in\Gamma$ excluded. Or do it completely different by letting $\gamma_\alpha=\min(\Gamma\setminus\langle \gamma_i\mid i<\alpha\rangle)$. I'll check which of these modification looks best.

Comment: I hope you are ok with my post-acceptance edits. I think the proof is much shortert and easier to comprehend now.

Comment: Yes, it's much more natural and easy to understand now. :) I took the liberty to fix a typo and a minor mistake at the very end, I hope you don't mind.